# Supertabular - part of caption and table missing

Tags: supertabular

I have a large table for my thesis that needs to be presented landscape and stretches over 2-3 pages, I have only included part of the table contents here.

My .tex file appears to compile without any problems but when I generate a pdf only part of the caption for this table is visible and only the first page of the table is produced. The table tail "Table continued on next page" is shown at the bottom of the table but on the next page it simply goes on to another/different table. The 'missing' part of the table does not appear anywhere else in the document.

I must be doing something wrong but I can't see what and have been struggling with this for hours so I really hope someone can help me with this.

Thank you in advance.

```
\clearpage
\begin{landscape}
\scriptsize
\tablefirsthead{
\hline
ID &RA (2000.0) &Dec (2000.0) &$J$ &$H$ &$K$ &Phot. type &Dist. &Spec. type &Kmatch &Dmatch &Letarte ID &$R-I$ &$CN-TiO$ &S/N\\
   &$\mathrm{(deg)}$ &$\mathrm{(deg)}$ &$\mathrm{(mag)}$ &$\mathrm{(mag)}$ &$\mathrm{(mag)}$ & &(kpc) & & & & &$\mathrm{(mag)}$ &$\mathrm{(mag)}$ &\\  
\hline}
\tablehead{
\hline
ID &RA &Dec &$J$ &$H$ &$K$ &Phot. type &Dist. &Spec. type &Kmatch &Dmatch &Letarte ID &$R-I$ &$CN-TiO$ &S/N\\
   &$\mathrm{(deg)}$ &$\mathrm{(deg)}$ &$\mathrm{(mag)}$ &$\mathrm{(mag)}$ &$\mathrm{(mag)}$ & &(kpc) & & & & &$\mathrm{(mag)}$ &$\mathrm{(mag)}$ &\\  
\hline}
\tabletail{
\hline
Table continued on next page.\\
\hline}
\tablelasttail{\hline}
\topcaption{List of $74$ candidate AGB sources in the inner region ($\leq 3$~kpc)
  for which spectra with S/N~$\geq 10$ were obtained. In column 1 those sources with a
  superscript reference number are in common with the catalogues of
  $^{1}$ \citet{2006A&A...454..717K}, $^{2}$
  \citet{2006A&A...456..905D}, $^{3}$ \citet{2013MNRAS.428.2216W} and
  $^{4}$ \citet{2012A&A...537A.108K} (see Table \ref{specsID}). In column 6 sources marked with
  a * were rejected from the photometric sample in Paper~I as they did not
  meet their strict quality control criterion but nevertheless could
  be classified by them. In column 8, source classifications preceded
  by a `d' denote dwarf stars, `e' indicates the presence of H$\alpha$
  in emission - many also show [S~II] and [N~II] (see
  Sect. \ref{emissI}) - and  a colon `:' indicates a tentative
  classification. The horizontal line separates those C-type sources
  misclassified as dK or dK7 by the matching program from the rest of
  the sample. A further $11$ sources which showed high energy emission lines are listed in Table \ref{emissTab}.}
\label{spectratab1}
\begin{supertabular}{lllllllllllrlll}
157078       &296.117004  &-14.632751  &16.46  &15.59  &15.26  &M    &1.77  &C:   &C5.5   &C      &87   &1.177  &0.371  &21\\
165127       &296.233887  &-14.671288  &17.14  &16.26  &16.01  &M    &1.13  &C    &C3.2   &C      &459  &1.102  &0.356  &12\\
195133$^{1}$   &296.229034  &-14.781347  &17.61  &16.51  &15.94  &C*   &0.20  &Ce:  &dK7  &K0III  &435   &1.39   &0.532  &22\\
195884$^{1}$   &296.213776  &-14.783867  &17.89  &17.08  &16.72  &M    &0.26  &C    &dK7  &K0IV   &333   &1.247  &0.443  &22\\
\hline
198595$^{1}$   &296.257843  &-14.793209  &17.91  &17.14  &16.88  &M    &0.19  &Ce:  &dK7  &K0III  &575   &1.218  &0.334  &19\\
199754$^{1}$   &296.208191  &-14.797331  &17.67  &16.91  &16.45  &C*   &0.25  &Ce   &dK7  &K0III  &309   &1.138  &0.338  &16\\
200300        &296.184326  &-14.799191  &17.83  &17.03  &16.78  &M    &0.44  &Ce:  &dK7  &K4III  &224   &1.104  &0.369  &15\\
\end{supertabular}
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). When asking questions it is better to provide a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) both in order to demonstrate what you are trying to do and to help others help you. The MWE should like like `\documentclass...\begin{document}...\end{document}`, it should compile and contain close to the minimal amount of code needed to explain/demonstrate what you are asking. This saves a lot of time for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do what you want with `longtable`. I can use `\small` rather than `scriptsize`. I add the caption`package` for a correct vertical spacing between caption and table, `makecell` to allow line breaks in columnheads with a commen formatting, `cellspace` to have a less tight vertical spacing of rows (it ensures a `minimal`vertical spacing above and below cells for columns whose specifier is prefixed with `C`, the `siunitx` package for alignment of decimal comma in numerical columns, and finally `threeparttablex` to separate the table caption from the explanations.

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ ltablex}%supertabular,
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font = small, labelfont = sc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{geometry}
    usepackage{array, booktabs, threeparttablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}
 \usepackage{cellspace}
 \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
 \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
% %
\setlength\tabcolsep{4.5pt}
    \begin{document}
\clearpage
\begin{landscape}
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\small\setTableNoteFont{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand\TPTminimum{\linewidth} %%% we want full width

\begin{TableNotes}
\item[] In column 1 those sources with a superscript reference number are in common with the catalogues of $¹$ \citet{2006A&A...454..717K}, $²$ \citet{2006A&A...456..905D}, $³$ \citet{2013MNRAS.428.2216W} and $⁴$ \citet{2012A&A...537A.108K} (see Table \ref{specsID}).
\item[] In column 6 sources marked with a * were rejected from the photometric sample in Paper~I as they did not meet their strict quality control criterion but nevertheless could be classified by them.
\item[] In column 8, source classifications preceded by a `d' denote dwarf stars, `e' indicates the presence of H$\alpha$ in emission -- many also show [S~II] and [N~II] (see Sect. \ref{emissI}) -- and a colon `:' indicates a tentative classification.
\item[] The horizontal line separates those C-type sources misclassified as dK or dK7 by the matching program from the rest of the sample.
\item[] A further $11$ sources which showed high energy emission lines are listed in Table \ref{emissTab}.
\end{TableNotes}
%%%
\begin{longtable}{S[table-format=6.0]S[table-format=3.6]S[table-format=-2.6]*{3}{S[table-format=2.2]}l S[table-format=1.2]*{3}{Cl}S[table-format=3.0] *{2}{S[table-format=1.3]} c }%
%%%%
\caption{List of $74$ candidate AGB sources in the inner region ($\leq 3$~kpc) for which spectra with S/N~$\geq 10$ were obtained. }
\label{spectratab1}\\
\insertTableNotes\\
\addlinespace[2ex]
\toprule
{\thead{ID}} & {\thead{RA (2000.0)\\(deg)}} & {\thead{Dec (2000.0)\\(deg)}} & {\thead{$J$\\(mag)}} & {\thead{$H$\\(mag)}} & {\thead{$K$\\(mag)}} & {\thead{Phot.\\ type}} &{\thead{Dist.\\(kpc)}} &{\thead{Spec.\\ type}} &{\thead{Kmatch}} & {\thead{Dmatch}} &{ \thead{ Letarte\\ ID}} & {\thead{$R-I$\\(mag)}} & {\thead{$CN-TiO$\\(mag)}} & {\thead{S/N}}\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
%%%%
\midrule
{\thead{ID}} & {\thead{RA\\(deg)}} & {\thead{Dec\\(deg)}} & {\thead{$J$\\(mag)}} & {\thead{$H$\\(mag)}} & {\thead{$K$\\(mag)}} & {\thead{Phot.\\ type}} &{\thead{Dist.\\(kpc)}} &{\thead{Spec.\\ type}} &{\thead{Kmatch}} & {\thead{Dmatch}} &{ \thead{ Letarte\\ ID}} & {\thead{$R-I$\\(mag)}} & {\thead{$CN-TiO$\\(mag)}} & {\thead{S/N}}\\
\midrule
\endhead
%%%%
\midrule
\multicolumn{13}{r}{Table continued on next page.}\\
\midrule
\endfoot
%%%%
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
157078 & 296.117004 & -14.632751 & 16.46 & 15.59 & 15.26 & M & 1.77 & C: & C5.5 & C & 87 & 1.177 & 0.371 & 21\\
165127 & 296.233887 & -14.671288 & 17.14 & 16.26 & 16.01 & M & 1.13 & C & C3.2 & C & 459 & 1.102 & 0.356 & 12\\
195133{\textsuperscript 1} & 296.229034 & -14.781347 & 17.61 & 16.51 & 15.94 & C* & 0.20 & Ce: & dK7 & K0III & 435 & 1.39 & 0.532 & 22\\
195884{$¹$} & 296.213776 & -14.783867 & 17.89 & 17.08 & 16.72 & M & 0.26 & C & dK7 & K0IV & 333 & 1.247 & 0.443 & 22\\
\cmidrule(lr){1-15}
198595{$¹$} & 296.257843 & -14.793209 & 17.91 & 17.14 & 16.88 & M & 0.19 & Ce: & dK7 & K0III & 575 & 1.218 & 0.334 & 19\\
199754{$¹$} & 296.208191 & -14.797331 & 17.67 & 16.91 & 16.45 & C* & 0.25 & Ce & dK7 & K0III & 309 & 1.138 & 0.338 & 16\\
200300 & 296.184326 & -14.799191 & 17.83 & 17.03 & 16.78 & M & 0.44 & Ce: & dK7 & K4III & 224 & 1.104 & 0.369 & 15\\
\end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{landscape}

    \end{document}
```

[image]